# Cannot run OrientDB in distributed mode with server has 2 IP address

Tags: orientdb

I have tried to run OrientDB with 2 servers as below:

- Server A: joined 2 networks. It has 2 IPs: 10.0.2.15 and 172.16.1.203
- Server B: joined 1 networks. It has IP: 172.16.1.91

Because serverA and serverB is in the same network 172.16.1.x, so, in hazelcast.xml, I have config IP 172.16.1.91 and 172.16.1.203 in TCP-IP section.

When I run server A with distributed mode, I see that it always show IP 10.0.2.15 was used as

[image]

And when I start Server B, it always throws an exception:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Cannot connect to the remote server '10.0.2.15:2424'
```

Please help!

Comment: Which version are you using? Can you share your hazelcast.xml?

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko, I use v2.2.12. You can get the hezalcast.xml [here](https://gist.github.com/heleyboo/65f626b5643b66d072f5865690cd710b)

Comment: I see different IP's in your config

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko, Assume serverA has IP: 192.168.33.10, and serverB has IP: 192.168.33.11.

Comment: Have you tried to run it with automatic discovery: multicast enabled setted to true ?

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko, Yes, I have tried to run with multicast but the same issue occurred.